# what is a recommended way to assign CRLF hotkey to button

Tags: vb.net

what is best way to assign CRLF hotkey to button?   In delphi it can be set to default one, but how its done in VB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign your button to the the form's .AcceptButton property.